# What is MyToken.address doing here?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, remix

This is the deployer contract of truffle react

```
var MyToken =  artifacts.require("MyToken.sol");
var MyTokenSale = artifacts.require("MyTokenSale.sol");

module.exports = async function(deployer){
    let addr = await wev3.eth.getAccounts();
    await deployer.deploy(MyToken, 10000);
    await deployer.deploy(MyTokenSale, 1, addr[0], MyToken.address);

    let instance = await MyToken.deployed();
    await instance.transfer(MyTokenSale.address, 10000);
}
```

MyToken contract

```
// contracts/GLDToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("GoldBucks", "GLD") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

MyTokenSale contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

import "./Crowdsale.sol";

contract MyTokenSale is Crowdsale{
    KycContract kyc;
    constructor(
        uint256 rate,
        address payable wallet,
        IERC20 token // this token will be sent to that particular addres that we specify in the deployer
    )

    Crowdsale(rate,wallet,token) public{

    }
}
```

What is the use of MyToken.address in the deployer contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your deployment script, parameters that follow the name of the smart contract (e.g `MyTokenSale`) are the constructor arguments for that contract.

So you can see arguments for `MyTokenSale` are:
`uint256 rate, address payable wallet, IERC20 token`

This means in the call `await deployer.deploy(MyTokenSale, 1, addr[0], MyToken.address);`

rate = 1,
wallet = addr[0],
token = MyToken.address

{contract}.address is available for access in truffle after the contract is deployed and references the contract's address.

HTH